# Perl STDERR printed in the wrong order with Tee

Tags: perl, bash, output, tee

I'm trying to redirect STDOUT and STDERR from a perl script - executed from a bash script - to  both screen and log file.

perlscript.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "This is a standard output";
print "This is a second standard output";
print STDERR "This is an error";
```

bashscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

./perlscript.pl 2>&1 | tee -a logfile.log
```

If I execute the perlscript directly the screen output is printed in the correct order :

```
This is a standard output
This is a second standard output
This is an error
```

But when I execute the bash script the STDERR is printed first (in both screen and file) :

```
This is an error
This is a standard output
This is a second standard output
```

With a bash script as child the output is ordered flawlessly. Is it a bug with perl or tee? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An usual trick to turnoff buffering is to set the variable **$|**. Add the below line at 
beginning of your script.

```
$| = 1;
```

This would turn the buffering off. Also refer to this excellent article by MJD explaining buffering in perl.  [Suffering from Buffering?](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html)

Answer (score 3):

I guess this has to do with the way STDOUT and STDERR buffers are flushed. Try

```
autoflush STDOUT 1;
```

at the beginning of your perl script so that STDOUT is flushed after each print statement.

Comment: Requires `use IO::Handle;` in order versions of Perl.

Comment: Nit: Indirect method calls are usually frowned upon. `STDOUT->autoflush(1);` or just `STDOUT->autoflush();` would be better.